# Error: error: Non-nullable instance field 'searchBar' must be initialized. (In _SearchBarDemoHomeState() { searchBar = SearchBar( )

Tags: flutter, search

Code:

```
class SearchBarDemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Search Bar Demo',
        theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
        home: new SearchBarDemoHome());
  }
}

class SearchBarDemoHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchBarDemoHomeState createState() => new _SearchBarDemoHomeState();
    }

class _SearchBarDemoHomeState extends State<SearchBarDemoHome> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  SearchBar searchBar;

  AppBar buildAppBar(BuildContext context) {
    return new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Search Bar Demo'),
        actions: [searchBar.getSearchAction(context)]);
  }


  void onSubmitted(String value) {
    setState(() {
      var context = _scaffoldKey.currentContext;

      if (context == null) {
        return;
      }

      ScaffoldMessenger.maybeOf(context)
          ?.showSnackBar(
          new SnackBar(content: new Text('You wrote "$value"!')));
    });
  }
  _SearchBarDemoHomeState() {
    searchBar =  SearchBar(
        inBar: false,
        buildDefaultAppBar: buildAppBar,
        setState: setState,
        onSubmitted: onSubmitted,
        onCleared: () {
          print("Search bar has been cleared");
        },
        onClosed: () {
          print("Search bar has been closed");
        });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Food3Rs'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error message: error: Non-nullable instance field 'searchBar' must be initialized. (not_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field at [startup_name] lib\main.dart:167)
No more details. Thank you very much for your help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Not enough words....So I cannot upload succesfully.Yep, I can upload it.

Answer (score 0):

```
_SearchBarDemoHomeState() {
    searchBar =  SearchBar(
        inBar: false,
        buildDefaultAppBar: buildAppBar,
        setState: setState,
        onSubmitted: onSubmitted,
        onCleared: () {
          print("Search bar has been cleared");
        },
        onClosed: () {
          print("Search bar has been closed");
        });
  }
```

Here you create a searchBar. Inside the creating the searchBar you try to create the appBar: `buildDefaultAppBar: buildAppBar,`

But when you want to create the appBar, you did not create the searcBar yet, although you try to use it:

```
AppBar buildAppBar(BuildContext context) {
    return new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Search Bar Demo'),
        actions: [searchBar.getSearchAction(context)]);
  }
```

So it throws this error. You try to use the `searchBar` before it is created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `SearchBar`. Either initialize it by saying `SearchBar searchBar = SearchBar(whateverGoesInside);` or if you want to initialize later, you can add the `late` keyword in front, like `late SearchBar searchBar;` which lets the compiler know that you intend to initialize it later.